# JPA Repository native query ignores ::timestamptz

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following native query.

The offset works when running in native SQL console. However, when I run the code in Java, it seems to ignore 'timestamptz at time zone 'Asia/Seoul'' argument and returns UTC result.

Is there anything that I need to set to make this work? (My database stores Timestamp in UTC)

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone 'Asia/Seoul') AS hour,\n"
              + "        COUNT(STO.id) AS count, SUM(STO.grandtotalprice) AS sum, AVG(STO.grandtotalprice) AS average\n"
              + "FROM store.storeorder AS STO\n"
              + "WHERE STO.store_id=?1 AND STO.createddate >= ?2 AND STO.createddate < ?3 AND STO.orderstatus IN ('CLOSED')\n"
              + "GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone 'Asia/Seoul') \n"
              + "ORDER BY hour ASC;",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<ReportHourly> hourlyReport(
      UUID storeId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what's going on.

My Hibernate is set to run in Asia/Seoul time zone.  So it had no effect.

I changed my hibernate timezone to UTC and it works now.

Thanks